# What is in `Err` when I try to join a panicked thread?

Tags: rust

The following code is a very simplified version. In this demo, thread `handle` panicked. The main thread want to join `handle`, so it will got an
`Err`.

```
use std::thread;
fn main() {
    let handle = thread::spawn(|| {
        panic!("panic in thread");
    });
    match handle.join() {
        Ok(_) => println!("panic in main, Ok"),
        Err(e) => println!("panic in main, Err {:?}", e),
    }
}
```

However, it only prints `panic in main, Err Any { .. }` about returned `Err` which contains no information.

My question is:

1. What is in this `Err`
2. Does `Err(e)` contains any information that can tell me any thing about the first panic? In this case, can I parse something from `Err(e)` from which I can find thread `handle` failed because of `panic!("panic in thread")`?

Comment: https://doc.rust-lang.org/1.54.0/std/thread/type.Result.html

Comment: IMO you shouldn't rely the result from panic since abort implementation of panic can be used.

Comment: @ÖmerErden This is a simplified version of my case, which does not involve panic_abort

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The [doc](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/std/thread/mod.rs.html#1369-1370) for `join` method specifically say, that `Err` will contain whatever is given to `panic`. So the example above works, if you retreive '&str' value from `Any`:

```
Err(e) => println!("panic in main, Err {:?}", e.downcast_ref::<&str>())

// -> panic in main, Err Some("panic in thread")
```

But if you use formatting, the value in `Err` will be `String` instead of `&str`:

```
panic!("Panic message: {}", "oh no!!!");

...

// to get the message above you need to use
Err(e) => println!("panic in main, Err {:?}", e.downcast_ref::<String>())
```